# Font settings not working in Xfce keyboard layout panel plugin in 16.06

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, fonts, keyboard-layout, xkb

There is [this bug (Text layout font size doesn't change)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/+bug/1510280): in `xfce4-xkb-plugin`, the panel applet that displays keyboard layouts, the font size settings are not followed (if 'text' is selected instead of 'flag').

The font type/family and style can be changed, but the keyboard language name (us, fr, etc) is displayed much bigger than it should.

[image]

Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: For me, it only displays the flag, not the abbreviation. How did you replace the flag?

Comment: @ipselute - in its settings or properties, the option to show image or text (http://goodies.xfce.org/_media/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin-0.5.3-settings.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, changing the font type (family) and style instead of font size may improve the appearance: some fonts may look better, as they are (and/or appear) smaller or thiner than others.

For example DejaVu Sans Extralight

[image]

shows like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this on my 64bit install by overwriting the */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin* with the [version from trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/xfce4-xkb-plugin/download), and by creating a symbolic link *@libxfce4util.so.6* pointing to *@libxfce4util.so.7* like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxfce4util.so.7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxfce4util.so.6
```

Comment: Could you give more details? - I think the idea is to unpack the deb and use the `xfce4-xkb-plugin` file from the deb to replace the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin`. But after doing this and the link, the keyboard switcher is absent from the list in the xfce4-panel option to add a new item.

Comment: doing all the above without first removing the Keyboard Layout panel app, the fix doesn't work, the font remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in later Xfce - tested in Mint 19.1 with xfce4-panel 4.12.2 (Xfce 4.12) - where the keyboard panel applet has a new setting called "widget size" which has nothing to do with fonts anymore.

[image]